# Windows Explorer crash on right-click since last Update

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-update

Yesterday I installed the pending updates from a week ago or so.

Since then Windows Explorer crashes when right-clicking any item. (The only item where it didn't crash on was on Computer.)

The event log shows:

```
Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 6.1.7601.17567, time stamp: 0x4d672ee4
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.24441, time stamp: 0x5cb935a7
Exception code: 0xc06d007e
Fault offset: 0x000000000000bdfd
Faulting process id: 0xff8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d51fa5574ad043
Faulting application path: C:\windows\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: dc15feee-8b99-11e9-9549-a41731b5c9d4
```

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: It appeared something went wrong in the update process. A revert to the 5/31 automatic system restore point solved the issue. I will later re-install the updates, hoping the process will work properly. Otherwise I'll revert again to 5/31.

Comment: I re-installed the updates on a freshly rebooted system and everything went fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem while right clicking in the Quick Access area (wanted to remove a folder from there) No idea which update or what caused this issue - any tips for possible solutions?

```
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 10.0.19041.1202, time stamp: 0xdba1e981
Faulting module name: SHELL32.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1202, time stamp: 0x5a3e4787
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000009305c
Faulting process id: 0x1e28
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7b161c6207c86
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
Report Id: becb6c70-7a3d-4d3c-bdb9-bbdb9ce7b63d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I performed a check in cmd:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow
>
> Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.
>
> Beginning verification phase of system scan. Verification 100%
> complete.
>
> Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Where can I go from here?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue when starting some programs, the logs read: `Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1202, time stamp: 0xef8beaeb`. I suspect the installation of `Ext2Fsd for Windows` caused that but I am not sure.