# Implications of roll-back a Windows Update?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I posted a
[question](https://superuser.com/questions/1447355/windows-explorer-crash-on-right-click-since-last-update)
about Windows Explorer crashing on right-click since I installed the pending update.

A solution could be to roll-back the update. But what are the consequences? Are updates cumulative and do they depend on each other? I.e., if I uninstall this update, will future updates install properly? Or can it destabilize my system?

Comment: Which Windows Update caused the problem? Was it the Mai 2019 update to Windows version 1903?

Comment: @harrymc, it was the May 2019 update. How can I find out the version number (Windows 7)? Help About says _Windows 7 Professional, Version 6.1 (build 7601: SP1)_.

Comment: Sorry, this is not it. I was thinking about Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 is not updated nowadays, but Microsoft did release
[KB4499175](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4499175/windows-7-update-kb4499175).
You may verify which one it was by, in Windows Update, checking the History section.

This is a security update that protects against several rare vulnerabilities,
which in my opinion are not absolutely required if they cause you a problem.

You may roll it back without fear. If any future update comes up that requires it,
it will be installed automatically again or the new update may fail.
In both cases you are ok.

If this doesn't help and you have a recent system restore point,
it might be easier to rollback to it.

Comment: Note: I always recommend upgrading to Windows 10, especially because of security concerns.

Comment: There is no 4499175 in my update list. There was however 4499164, which I uninstalled. Unfortunately to no avail. It still crashes on right-click. I'll keep uninstalling. Could something have gone wrong in the update process that cannot be fixed by uninstalls?

Comment: If you have a recent system restore point, it might be easier to rollback to it. Regarding the Windows 10 Start menu : See [Open-Shell](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu) - I use it and it's better than that of Windows 7.

Comment: Yes! That worked! Automatic Restore Point of 5/31. Thanks very much! As I now assume that something went wrong in the update process, and Windows bombards me with messages about new updates, I'll just go ahead and install them. I now know I can revert to 5/31. Lesson learned: reboot system before installing updates.

Comment: I added the system restore advice to the answer, so you may accept it. If the same problem happens again, it might be safer to do the Windows update while booting in Safe mode with Network.

Comment: I re-installed the updates on a freshly rebooted system and everything went fine.